# What reaction would take place on an electrode in a secondary cell if it were charged and the other electrode removed?

Tags: redox, electrolysis

I'm reading a book that covers the basics of electrical theory and I'm at a chapter that discusses the concept of a secondary cell. The author includes the redox reactions that take place in a primary cell when it is charging/discharging.

The secondary cell is comprised of an anode (composed of PbO<sub>2</sub>) and a cathode (composed of Pb) submerged in a solution of H<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub>. As it discharges both electrodes are plated with PbSO<sub>4</sub> until they are fully covered, at which point the reactions that produce a charge for the battery cease and the original H<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub> is now diluted with H<sub>2</sub>O.

My question focuses on the charging aspect of it not the discharging (because I have an easier time framing my question from this perspective) but I want to preface this aspect with two quotes the author said earlier in the chapter:

First quote: "From previous information, we found that H<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub>, when charging or discharging a cell, dissociates into hydrogen H<sup>+</sup> ions and sulfate SO<sub>4</sub><sup>=</sup> ions."

Second quote (this quote comes from a section describing a different cell): "The zinc element or electrode, when immersed in the acid, starts to dissolve, leaving its electrons behind and the zinc goes into solution as Zn<sup>++</sup> ions. This action stops very shortly, as the zinc plate becomes negative and ceases to throw off positive ions. The amount of zinc thus dissolved is very minute. If the negative zinc plate is connected externally by a wire to the copper plate, an electrical current will flow from the negative zinc plate through the external wire to the copper plate (positive). As the negative charge of the zinc plate is thus removed, more Zn<sup>++</sup> ions go into the solution"

As the original secondary cell I mentioned recharges the PbSO<sub>4</sub> plating reverts to the composition of it's respective electrode and the diluted H<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub> reverts to it's original solution. The reactions that take place when the cell is recharging as quoted from the book:

*Negative Plate*: PbSO<sub>4</sub> + 2H<sup>+</sup> + 2e --> Pb + H<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub>

*Positive Plate*: PbSO<sub>4</sub> + SO<sub>4</sub><sup>=</sup> - 2e --> Pb(SO<sub>4</sub>)<sub>2</sub>

I presume that each plate is a half reaction; the negative plate is a reduction half reaction; the positive plate is an oxidation half reaction; I believe these half reactions can be combined into the full reaction: 2PbSO<sub>4</sub> + 2H<sup>+</sup> + SO<sub>4</sub><sup>=</sup> --> Pb(SO<sub>4</sub>)<sub>2</sub> + Pb + H<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub>. Please correct me if I'm wrong about what these half reactions are or about how I combined them; I have only just recently learned about redox reactions in order to better understand this chapter.

Now for the question this has all been building up to; if the positive plate were removed during the recharge process would the half reaction that takes place on the negative plate become the half reaction: PbSO<sub>4</sub> + 2H<sup>+</sup> + SO<sub>4</sub><sup>=</sup>  --> Pb + H<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub> + SO<sub>4</sub><sup>=</sup> for a short period of time until the solution becomes negative with SO<sub>4</sub><sup>=</sup> anions and ceases to throw off H<sup>+</sup> cations (similar to what happens in the second quote and considering what happens in the first quote)?

If this is the case, then I don't know how the difference of charge between the reaction and product side is possible. The only thing I can imagine is that the SO<sub>4</sub><sup>=</sup> is just a spectator and does not participate in the actual reaction.

Comment: PbO2, not Pb(SO4)2

Comment: $Pb(SO_{4})_2$ breaks down in the presence of $H_2O$ to arrive at $PbO_2 + 2 H_2SO_4$

Comment: Rather $\ce{Pb^4+ + 2 H2O -> PbO2 + 4 H+}$  ( using \ce{} ).  There is no $\ce{Pb(SO4)2}$

Comment: The sulfate of the electrode must bond with the hydrogen in the end to restore the solution for further charge and the electrode itself. Also Pb does not react with $H_2O$ during electrolysis. How did you get to Pb from PbSO_4 (what both plates are coated with)?

Comment: And: $\ce{PbSO4(s) + 2 H2O -> PbO2(s) + HSO4- +  3 H+ + 2 e-}$

Comment: $\ce{Pb^2+ + 2 e- -> Pb}$ respectively $\ce{PbSO4(s) + H+ + 2 e- -> Pb(s) + HSO4-}$.

Comment: Note that primary cells are not supposed to be charged. Secondary ones are.

Comment: Sulphate (hydrogen sulphate) ions are spectator ions, aside of reversible forming of PbSO4(s), as you correctly   assumed.

Comment: Half reactions do not depend on the circuit being closed. If the circuit is open, the electrode potential converges to its equilibrium one, where the half reaction in ongoing by the same rate in both directions.

Comment: May I have your thoughts on 2 things? First thing: Are you saying that it's impossible for the sulfate anions to react with the positive plate when it's oxidized during the recharge process? Right now I'm thinking that it's possible for both reactions to take place when the positive plate is oxidized; one possibility is that the negative sulfate ions (from $H_2SO_4$) bond with $PbSO_4$ to arrive at $Pb(SO_4)_2$; the other possibility is that the negative oxygen ions (from $H_2O$ like you said) bond with Pb from $PbSO_4$. If it's not possible for the sulfate ions to bond, then my book is wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113694/discussion-between-matthew-s-and-poutnik).

Comment: Second thing: When you say that half reactions do not depend on the circuit being closed I assume you mean the half reaction on the negative plate would remain the same if the positive plate were removed (correct me if my assumption is wrong).

Comment: Isn't that what I did with my extrapolated reaction of what would happen if the positive plate were removed? The only difference between my extrapolated half reaction and the one given is that the negative sulfate ion doesn't participate in the reaction so it's on both the reactant and product side. I only included the sulfate ion to illustrate that without the positive plate it wouldn't have anything to bond with (assuming that a negative sulfate ion could bond with the positive plate at all).